# Use of past tense when describing upcoming event

Tags: past-tense

> Barbara Kelley, executive director of the Hearing Loss Association of
> America, an advocacy organization, told me that she can’t wait for
> more affordable and accessible hearing help. “I’m really excited for
> the market to open up to see what we **got** and see how people are
> reacting,” she said.

I have encountered the sentences above in a news article featuring a regulatory change that will allow Americans to buy hearing aids without a prescription.

I can't wrap my head around why the past tense form *got* is used instead of *are getting* or *will get* in the last sentence.

The opening-up of the market is a future event. Indeed, that's why the "be plus -ing" form is used in the following section *see how people are reacting* to describe an upcoming event.

Could you provide an explanation about the use of the past tense?

P.S.
The news article is not only about existing hearing aids becoming available for purchase over the counter, but also technology companies such as Apple and Bose aiming to enter the market with new types of product. So, the expression *what we **got*** appears, to me, to be referring to completely new products yet to be offered.

In order to give more context to the sentence in question, I will quote a longer version from the New York Times article.

> Experts told me that when the F.D.A. moves ahead, it’s likely to lead
> to new products and ideas to change hearing aids as we know them.
>
> Imagine Apple, Bose or other consumer electronics companies making
> hearing aids more stylish and relatively affordable — with people
> having confidence that the devices had been vetted by the F.D.A. Bose
> told me that it’s working on over-the-counter hearing aid technology.
>
> Barbara Kelley, executive director of the Hearing Loss Association of
> America, an advocacy organization, told me that she can’t wait for
> more affordable and accessible hearing help. “I’m really excited for
> the market to open up to see what we **got** and see how people are
> reacting,” she said.

Comment: We all make mistakes. In speech, one can't edit as completely.

Comment: It's informal speech in some American dialects. "Come see what we got," and so on.

Comment: It's past tense because she's referring to things they already have rather than things they are going to obtain. Even if the market hasn't yet opened, they may already have things. "we have got" would be more correct, but it's very common to use past tense instead of perfect. Saying "see what we get" would have a different meaning, implying it's uncertain what they will have. As another comments says, "we got" means something similar to "we have",  i.e. "we have already obtained", but this explains the logic.

Comment: I think the question can be well related to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166206/it-is-high-time-we-leave-or-it-is-high-time-we-left

Comment: In addition, the old ways of reporting supports the view. E.g. He said, "I do it daily, and I am going to do it next week too." becomes, "He said that he did it daily and he was going to do it the next/ following week too." This still refers to the future, but written in the past tense.

Answer (score 3):

It's not past tense at all, nor a mistake. "What we got" is an informal (very informal) idiom for "what we have."

She's saying, "I'm really excited for the market to open up to see what we have [on the market]."

You're not going to find it in real dictionaries, but here's an example from [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=what+we+got+next+mate%3F):

> what we got next mate?
> A simple Term uttered most commonly by a person in Secondary School who hasn't got a *** clue what the next class is.

Meaning, "What do we have next, mate?"

Comment: I agree.  It appears in a respectable (I hope) newspaper, which (correctly) prints the quotation as uttered.  I have heard this type of colloquialism used to project an air of tough realism:  "Let's see what we got".  Given its colloquial nature, there is no point in choosing between its being virtually present ("..see what we <have> got") or simple past of 'get'.  The speaker is not thinking about that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what she is talking about is the market of people's need, what people are looking for by way of helpful devices. She is not referring to the coming of those devices but the need for them. The need is what they already *have* or *got*.

It could be phrased better but as others have said she is speaking and not writing.

Answer (score 0):

Business is a game of timing right? Shutters are down for customers right now but people *have built/are busy building* behind the shutter. Holding that thought..

Since, our dear speaker is excited and would like to assume that there are good things ready and waiting to be launched once the market opens, she goes on to use "got" instead of "getting" or "will get".

Another way of justifying her usage of "got" could be that she might be taking a holistic view of the entire system. A system of which we are all a part. But because we work in specialised silos, often the left hand doesn't know *about what* or *how much* right hand has progressed. Still, both hands belong to the same system. Hence, the usage of "what *we* got" instead of "what *we* are getting".
Where use of ***we*** the latter will be considering the consumers as a disconnected entity, not part of the system.

Comment: Good explanation. The wording is most likely not a grammatical mistake, but a reflection of the speaker’s concept of the situation. The work on hearing aids (for example) has been completed, but the products are not yet visible to the buying public. If they are unveiled at a point in the future, it is natural to refer to them in the past tense. Anyone who doubts this should think about how they describe the opening of a Christmas present or other type of parcel that we wait to open.